# Hadoop : How to obtain or calculate queue weight?

Tags: hadoop, resourcemanager

I know these values can be obtained within the fairscheduler.xml file. But is there a way we can compute this number using one of the resource managers RESTFul endpoints?

References I've been sifting through for this information:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

No way of obtaining queue weight other than analyzing the fairscheduler.xml on the resource manager node

Desired Solution:

```
queueWeight = ( some_X_value_from_RM_endpoint / some_Y_value_from_RM_endpoint)
```

Example Of Queue with Weight:

```
  <queue name="sample_queue">
    <minResources>10000 mb,5 vcores,5 disks</minResources>
    <weight>2.0</weight>
    <schedulingPolicy>fair</schedulingPolicy>
  </queue>
```

How can I compute/obtain `weight = 2.0` without examining the `Fairscheduler` file? Is there a computation against some other parameters to get this value?

Comment: "Current applications, queues, and fair shares can be examined through the ResourceManager’s web interface, at http://*ResourceManager URL*/cluster/scheduler.", it's not deriving though and ui can change any time.

Comment: @patrungel this will give you some of the fairschduler.xml information but not the weight